# mysql Workbench insert default

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using the Inserts tab in mysql wb. If I don't specify any value it just inserts NULL and not the value when exporting.

```
INSERT INTO foo(foo1, foo2, foo3) VALUES (NULL, "concrete", NULL)
```

instead it should use the default value where not specified, is that possible with workbench?

```
INSERT INTO foo(foo2) VALUES ("concrete")
```

or

```
INSERT INTO foo(foo1, foo2, foo3) VALUES (default1, "concrete", default3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use the `DEFAULT` keyword.  As explained in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html):

> Use the keyword DEFAULT to set a column explicitly to its default
>   value. This makes it easier to write INSERT statements that assign
>   values to all but a few columns, because it enables you to avoid
>   writing an incomplete VALUES list that does not include a value for
>   each column in the table. Otherwise, you would have to write out the
>   list of column names corresponding to each value in the VALUES list.
>
> You can also use DEFAULT(col_name) as a more general form that can be
>   used in expressions to produce a given column's default value.

So, try this:

```
INSERT INTO foo(foo1, foo2, foo3)
    VALUES (DEFAULT, 'concrete', DEFAULT);
```